# Issue in creating cluster the machine type n1-standard-1?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Hi I doing Managing Deployments Using Kubernetes Engine lab. So I have been stuck with the problem in creating a cluster with five n1-standard-1. I am running the same command but I don't know why I am not getting the same results. When I run this command I am getting another machine type. Hence the same cluster is not being created.

```
gcloud container clusters create bootcamp --num-nodes 5 --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,storage-rw"
```

After running this command cluster is created whose machine type is e2-medium but the lab wants the n1-standard-1 machine type.
The only difference is in machine type. I have tried it but not getting the right answer.

Comment: Edit your question and replace the images with text. What is your problem?

Comment: @John Hanley I have issue in creating a cluster. The machine type is e2-medium but this quest want an n1-standard-n1 machine type. So I have tried it too many times but the result is same.

Comment: Edit your question and replace the images with text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--machine-type) when creating the cluster.

Add the command line option: `--machine-type=n1-standard-1`

```
gcloud container clusters create bootcamp --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --num-nodes 5 --scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,storage-rw"
```